# Assigning an ipv4 address to (LXD) linux containers

Tags: networking, lxc, lxd

I've got a home server running with a bunch of linux containers and they're all getting their ip addresses assigned automatically via dhcp on my router.

I'd like to be able to assign ip addresses manually to each container but I seem to be having a bit of trouble finding a working example of how to do that exactly.

I have my containers setup so that they're getting addresses that start with 192.168.1.xxx and are accessible by other devices on my network instead of the private? addresses (10.whatever) that the default LXD settings give.

An example of some of my containers (deluge is also connected to a vpn):

```
+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------+-----------+
|    NAME    |  STATE  |              IPV4              | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| deluge     | RUNNING | 192.168.1.17 (eth0)            |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|            |         | 10.3.83.122 (tun0)             |      |            |           |
+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| emby       | RUNNING | 192.168.1.19 (eth0)            |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| grocery    | RUNNING | 192.168.1.52 (eth0)            |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------+-----------+
```

One example tutorial I tried that didn't seem to work is [this blog post on medium](https://medium.com/@ali_oguzhan/lxd-assigning-static-ip-to-containers-ecf558982071). I like the simplicity of his method but unfortunately, it seems to have 0 effect on my containers. His `/etc/default/lxd-bridge` file is slightly different than mine though. He has `LXD_BRIDGE=""` whereas mine is set to `LXD_BRIDGE="br0"`.

Contents of my **host** `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# this is empty
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports enp7s0

iface enp7s0 inet manual
```

Contents of my default lxc profile which is currently assigned to all containers:

```
config:
  environment.http_proxy: ""
  user.network_mode: ""
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: br0
    type: nic
name: default
used_by: []
```

All my containers are running recent versions of ubuntu.

LXD version 2.0.11

Comment: I've yet to try this myself, but have you tried **1)** creating a config file with the static config under `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`, _and_ **2)** creating the `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg` with the line `network: {config: disabled}`? My clean install of a 16.04-based container has the file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg` and it has a comment with the info I just mentioned, which seems related to this issue and notes: `Changes to it will not persist across an instance. To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities...`, repeating the above.

Comment: I tried out a few things, including the above, but so far, I can't get it to work. (The `networking.service` will exit with an error when you try to restart it to apply the changes.) I'll try a few more things to see if I manage to find a solution for it.